# При сворачивании формы закрывается приложение

Tags: c#, winforms

c#
Суть такова.
Имеется 2 формы в приложении, одна - логин форма, вторая где после логина покажется информация.

форма логина - loginForm
форма инфы - MainForm

При успешном логине, loginFrom закрывается и запускается MainForm

```
           //запуск главной формы
            MainForm mf = new MainForm();
            //Закрытие и запуск
            this.Hide();
            mf.ShowDialog();
```

в MainForm Имеются кнопки для сворачивания приложения в трей

```
private void hideMenuStrip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            //this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            //если скрываем прогу, то скрываем везде кроме нотифи икон
            this.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
    }
```

Но при скрытии MainForm программа либо закрывается, либо открывается loginForm
А мне нужно чтоб именно сворачивалась.

Закрывается в том случае, если я добавлю ко всем скрывающим кнопкам внизу

```
this.Dispose();
```

Вообще проявляется проблема в том, что при сворачивании MainForm почему то запускается функция Load в loginForm

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь всю логику втиснуть в обработчики событий окон. Попробуйте перенести логику, связанную с авторизацией, в Program.cs. Сначала показывать окно диалога с помощью `ShowDialog()`, а потом уже открывать главное окно приложения.

```
LoginForm loginDialog = new LoginForm();
if (loginDialog.ShowDialog(null) == DialogResult.OK)
{
   Password = loginDialog.TextBox1.Text;
}
loginDialog.Dispose();

if (Password=="MyPassword")
  Application.Run();
```

См. также [[1]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx), [[2]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx).